# MS-Word printing all or nothing. How to solve it?

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I have a document set up as a Letter-sized page configured as a booklet that, when I attempt to print it, does not allow me to print custom pages. It's all or nothing.

The image below shows that the print options are all grayed-out except the "Print All Pages".

Has anyone encountered this problem?

[image: Attempting to print custom pages]

> Just some information about the document.
>
> **Document Information:**
>
> - It has a Table of Contents
> - It has 235 pages
> - Page size: Letter
> - Margins:
>
>   - Top: 1.5 cm
>   - Bottom: 1 cm
>   - Inside: 1 cm
>   - Outside: 1.5 cm
>   - Gutter: 0 cm

Comment: Are you able to print other documents?

Comment: Without any problem. It's just this one doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word will not print a partial booklet. It wouldn't really make sense to do it, as the formatting of the booklet (page order, and what goes on the other side of each page) depends on the booklet as a whole.

Refer to https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/printing-side-by-side-in-booklet-but-only-selected/b1dac5cb-f121-43ae-b90f-0e6c05162c3e

Comment: I see... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to print a booklet in MS Word, but the custom pages option is grayed out, and you can only print all pages as a whole. This problem can occur due to various reasons, such as printer driver issues, formatting, or Word settings. Here are a few possible solutions to try:

1. Check the printer driver: Sometimes printer drivers can cause issues while printing. Make sure that your printer driver is up-to-date and compatible with your version of MS Word. If you are using an older printer, you might need to update its driver or use a different printer.
2. Check formatting issues: Formatting issues can also cause problems while printing. Check if there are any blank pages in your document and remove them. Also, make sure the margins are set correctly, and there is no extra white space on the pages.
3. Try printing as a PDF: You can try printing your booklet as a PDF and then print the PDF instead. To do this, go to File > Save As and select the PDF format. Then open the PDF in a PDF reader and try printing from there.